# How does a client socket application identify the server application on the same host computer

Tags: sockets

I have been trying to learn socket programming in C++ and got some progress for the basics. But I understood that basics are not fundamentals.

One of those fundamentals is about the question which is stated in the title. Lets say I have two separate applications running on the same computer. One of them has a server socket and the other one has a client.

When the server gets an IP address automatically, how can client find the server? Do I have to assign an IP address that is known by the client? In that case, maybe that IP address is not available on the network.

Or can client find and connect to the server by sone kind of name or id?

Comment: The hostname 'localhost' is resolved locally - just use it.  It's 127.0.0.1 by default,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address of any server in the same host is 127.0.0.1 unless the server has bound to a specific, different IP address. As @MartinJames points out, you can use 'localhost' as the hostname for that, except on certain broken Linux distributions.

Comment: "unless"? Isn't 127.0.0.1 **always** the address of the local host (but it could **also** have a different address on a network).

Comment: IIRC, '127.0.0.1' is in the 'hosts' file on Linux and can be edited.  Even Windows used to have a 'hosts' file with that entry, but I'm guessing that it's now been registryized.

Comment: Aparrently, it still is in 'hosts': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

Comment: @Dukeling If the server has bound to another IP address, you can't connect to it via 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @MartinJames The hosts file is a hostname to IP address mapping (not the other way around), meaning removing that entry doesn't change where `127.0.0.1` points to.

Comment: @EJP [I don't think](http://www.tech-faq.com/127-0-0-1.html) [you're right about that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) (unless I'm misunderstanding you).

Comment: @Dukeling There's nothing in that link that contradicts what I have stated here. I tested it. If you want to debate this further, try it first.

Answer (score 1):

Have the server bind to all interfaces and have the client lookup 'localhost' by name; it's resolved locally, (ie. no external DNS service required), to an IP address stored in a 'hosts' file, and is set by default to 127.0.0.1

Google 'hosts file'

Comment: What if I have two server and two client application? Client1 communicates with Server1 and Client2 communicates with Server2. Then 127.0.0.1 will be assigned to both servers? How would clients distinguish which server to connect?

Comment: ^^ listening port number.  It needs to be unique per server, eg. server A listens on 127.0.0.1:80, server B on 127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: @MartinJames It needs to be unique per IP address actually, except that if you bind to INADDR_ANY:port you can't reuse that port with a specific IP address.